# HIghcharts, Selecting a second Point within the Point.select event

Tags: javascript, events, select, callback, highcharts

```
$(function () {
  var chart = {
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        point: {
          'events' : {
            select: function(){
              var pId = this.series.data.indexOf(this);

              var chart1 = $('#container').highcharts();
              var chart2 = $('#container2').highcharts();


        //These are the extra selects I want to happen
        //chart1.series[0].data[5].select(true,true);
        //chart2.series[0].data[pId].select();

            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4,
             129.2, 144.0, 176.0,
             135.6, 148.5, 216.4,
             194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }] 
  };
  $('#container').highcharts(chart);
  $('#container2').highcharts(chart);

  var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

  i = 0;
  $('#button').click(function() {
    if (i == chart.series[0].data.length) 
    i = 0; 

    chart.series[0].data[i].select();
    i++;
  });


});
```

<strike>http://jsfiddle.net/rphne/</strike>

http://jsfiddle.net/rphne/5/

You can see what I'm trying to achieve there. Essentially, I want to select a point on the same graph, as well as a point on a second graph after the select event occurs.

In the example above, it should select the same point on chart 1 and chart 2, as well as chart1 selecting a second point on itself.

I figured just doing a .Select(true,true) would accumulate, however this fails when done within the select event. I believe I'm looking for a callback event kind of thing, so that after the Select has successfully completed, I can then do my extra selects.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

In the button action you select only one point from one chart, because use use `chart.series[0].data[i].select();` in first object. Only what you need is add the same action for second chart.

http://jsfiddle.net/rphne/1/

EDIT: 
You can also use setState() function to sychronise both charts.
http://jsfiddle.net/rphne/6/

Comment: Yeah, In this example the functionality is easily placed within the .select button, however what I'm intending on using this functionality by someone clicking on the graph themselves.

That's why I've been attempting to have the functionality within the event, as it's the first port of call where I'll be able to manipulate things.

Comment: Thats cool! One final question if you don't mind,

http://jsfiddle.net/rphne/7/

I've added a second data series, when you click a point on the series in the top chart, it's meant to highlight the same point in series 2. It highlights it and marks it as selected, but when you hover out and back in again you can see that it's actually un selected. Any advice?

Comment: So when You click in 1st chart, 1st serie, selected point should be only in second serie, or not. I'm not sure...

Comment: Ignoring the bottom chart, when you click on top chart series 1, it is meant to select the same point on series 2 (and vice versa).

It shows that it has selected the same point on S2 (with the white mark), but when you hover over it, it disappears. Showing only 1 point selected.